# Nvidia drivers making unity not working fine

Tags: 12.04, unity, drivers, nvidia, lts

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Gigabyte P35K. Unity was working fine at the first boot, but then I installed the Nvidia driver and now when I move a window it is pretty slow, when I take the window to one border it does not resize, etc... I know that it is not a problem from the unity configuration because I broke my last install trying to fix this problem...

Is there a problem with the latest nvidia driver? I installed it using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: You might be running in 2D mode. You can check quickly with `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`. Have you activated any of the Additional Drivers for Nvidia in System Settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that after installing `nvidia-current` there is a new pilot in the Additional Drivers section of the system settings. Activating this new pilot fixed everything!

Hope it works if it happens to someone else.